Flutter Math (used to displays equations in Flutter: flutter_math_fork 0.7.2) does not even compile due to "hashCode" method undefined or not found
This is the first time that I'm trying to use flutter_math_fork 0.7.2 package to display Tex equations but it does not even compile due to the following error ("hashValues" is not found or defined):
flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:603:23: Error: The method 'hashValues' isn't defined for the class 'SelectionStyle'.
 - 'SelectionStyle' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/widgets/selectable.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hashValues'.
  int get hashCode => hashValues(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/ast/options.dart:400:7: Error: The method 'hashValues' isn't defined for the class 'FontOptions'.
 - 'FontOptions' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/ast/options.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/ast/options.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hashValues'.
      hashValues(fontFamily.hashCode, fontWeight.hashCode, fontShape.hashCode);
      ^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/ast/options.dart:434:7: Error: The method 'hashValues' isn't defined for the class 'PartialFontOptions'.
 - 'PartialFontOptions' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/ast/options.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.7.2/lib/src/ast/options.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'hashValues'.
      hashValues(fontFamily.hashCode, fontWeight.hashCode, fontShape.hashCode);
      ^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

My code:
import 'package:flutter_math_fork/flutter_math.dart';
...
child: choicesContainsTexEquation ? Text(text) : Math.tex(text),

The variable text above is read from a JSON file. With both texts (decoded as Strings) below, the same error occurs (whether trying to run on Android emulator or Chrome):
"text":"test" and "text": "e^{i\\pi}+1=0"
On pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_math_fork: ^0.7.2

What could be the issue?
I've tried changing both the text (using a Tex equation or "plain" text) and the platform (Android emulator and Chrome), and the same error occurs.

The issue here is in package itself. I guess this package is poorly maintained lately, so things like this may happen.
I think the only thing you can do, if you really depend on this package, is to use a fork where this particular problem fixed. Or maybe create your own fork with fixes.
I searched GitHub a little and found fork where your problem is fixed, here: https://github.com/Telosnex/flutter_math_fork_fork.git
Particularly, here is commit with fix.
You can try to use it in your project, just modify tour podspec.yaml like this:
  flutter_math_fork:
    git: https://github.com/Telosnex/flutter_math_fork_fork.git

But, more creating your own fork with fixes is more robust way, in my opinion.

Thank you very much! By now, using the existing fork you mentioned works for me. I just had to add to pubspec.yaml the following: flutter_math_fork:     git:       url: https://github.com/Telosnex/flutter_math_fork_fork.git. On main.dart, I added import 'package:flutter_math_fork/flutter_math.dart';

it works for me to, i had try all others options without succes (flutter_math, flutter_math_fork, flutter_tex). Thus in december 2024, it's the solution that works for me.
